# start up tomcat error in My Eclipse Blue 2014

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to configure Tomcat 7 in My Eclipse Blue ans run it alone. I am getting the error in console as:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Rule
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:406)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

How can I resolve this error?